# Create a Windows Session from a service via the Win32 API

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a windows service that can create an executable in the users windows session, via calling the "CreateProcessAsUser" function. This works fine as long as there is a windows session already there. In the case that there isn't one already I'd like to be able to create one programmatically. Is this is possible? Can't seem to find a function to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite the solution for the question I asked, but it was the solution that helped achieve what I was trying to achieve by asking this question, if you see what I mean.

Rather than have having a windows services that creates a server session you can configure windows to automatically logon at boot time. This still means someone could accenditally log off, but cures the main reason for sessions disappearing: the server being rebooted. Use the following steps to activate auto-logon:

1. Press the Windows key + R on your keyboard to launch the “Run” dialog box.
2. Type regedit and hit enter to open the Registry Editor
3. Then browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\
4. Set AutoAdminLogon  = 1 (create it if doesn't exist its a string variable)
5. Set DefaultUserName = your username (create it if doesn't exist its a string variable)
6. Set DefaultPassword = your password (create it if doesn't exist its a string variable)

Instructions were taken from this post:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/coolstuff/Tip-Auto-Login-Your-Windows-7-User-Account

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a new session from a service. Sessions are managed by the OS. New ones get created when users logon interactively.

Comment: You can use the WTS API, such as `WTSGetActiveSessionId()` and `WTSEnumerateSessions()`, to determine if a user session exists before calling `CreateProcessAsUser()`.

Comment: For the record: Windows Server 2012 supports the Remote Desktop Protocol Provider API, which you could use to create a session programatically.  Also, at least in theory, you could write your own Remote Desktop client (or modify one of the open source clients) to create a new session on any supported version of Windows - provided that Remote Desktop is enabled, of course.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is what I do already, I'm trying to avoid problems where the session has been unexpectedly closed.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks, this sounds like solutions though have to admit I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: @Robert: you and me both.  If you do manage to get a working solution, and are able to share it, could you let me know?  (My profile includes my email address.)

Answer (score 1):

@Robert, I know this is an old question and that you've already found something that works for you but in my case I was looking for something similar to your original question and I did finally figure it out so I thought I'd share.  My solution uses only .NET and a COM reference not the Win32 API mentioned in your title, but I'm guessing that wasn't really a requirement for you.

I've written a simple utility to using the Remote Desktop ActiveX control (COM Reference).  If you paste this code into a Class Library you can then call it by simply passing in the server, username, domain, and password and everything is done for you without any other interaction required.  Once the method is complete you can then call your "CreateProcessAsUser" Code.  I've written this utility in a way so that you could call it every time but initiating an RDP session takes several seconds so for performance sake I'd suggest you write another method to enumerate the sessions and see if your user is logged in and only call this utility when you determine that your user isn't logged in (That's what I did in my actual project).  If you feel you need help with that post in the comments and I'll share how I did that but It's not really part of this question so for now I'm leaving it out.

Here's a link back to my question that has a few more requirements/details  than this question.

[Create Windows Session programmatically from Console or Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801093/create-windows-session-programmatically-from-console-or-windows-service/52801094#52801094)

And here's my RDP utility.  After you put this code in a class library you can then call it from a console app, winForms app, or from a windows service running on the same machine or from a remote machine.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AxMSTSCLib;

namespace Utility.RemoteDesktop
{
    public class Client
    {
        private int LogonErrorCode { get; set; }

        public void CreateRdpConnection(string server, string user, string domain, string password)
        {
            void ProcessTaskThread()
            {
                var form = new Form();
                form.Load += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    var rdpConnection = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting();
                    form.Controls.Add(rdpConnection);
                    rdpConnection.Server = server;
                    rdpConnection.Domain = domain;
                    rdpConnection.UserName = user;
                    rdpConnection.AdvancedSettings9.ClearTextPassword = password;
                    rdpConnection.AdvancedSettings9.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
                    if (true)
                    {
                        rdpConnection.OnDisconnected += RdpConnectionOnOnDisconnected;
                        rdpConnection.OnLoginComplete += RdpConnectionOnOnLoginComplete;
                        rdpConnection.OnLogonError += RdpConnectionOnOnLogonError;
                    }
                    rdpConnection.Connect();
                    rdpConnection.Enabled = false;
                    rdpConnection.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    Application.Run(form);
                };
                form.Show();
            }

            var rdpClientThread = new Thread(ProcessTaskThread) { IsBackground = true };
            rdpClientThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            rdpClientThread.Start();
            while (rdpClientThread.IsAlive)
            {
                Task.Delay(500).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }

        private void RdpConnectionOnOnLogonError(object sender, IMsTscAxEvents_OnLogonErrorEvent e)
        {
            LogonErrorCode = e.lError;
        }
        private void RdpConnectionOnOnLoginComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LogonErrorCode == -2)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"    ## New Session Detected ##");
                Task.Delay(10000).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            var rdpSession = (AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting)sender;
            rdpSession.Disconnect();
        }
        private void RdpConnectionOnOnDisconnected(object sender, IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEvent e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the LogonUser function?

http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32LogonUser.htm

Comment: Unfortunately "session" is an overloaded term in Windows.  In this context, I think the OP is talking about Remote Desktop (aka Windows Terminal Services) session rather than a logon session.  Robert, could you please clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference here, it doesn't need to be a remote desktop session per se, but it does need to have a sessionid > 0 so that it can execute programs with a gui.

Comment: Remote Desktop Services is the part of Windows that allows user switching and session zero isolation, as well as actual Remote Desktop connections.  You're definitely talking about Remote Desktop session IDs here, so LogonUser won't solve your problem.