# How to launch application on non-logged on user's desktop from service on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, service, desktop, account

I am trying to create a service which does following:

1. Logging in as a user with specified username/password
2. Running an application on the desktop of logged in user of step 1

Note: before step 1, user is not logged on. (something like right after machine is rebooted)

The expected result is, the user should be able to see the UI of launched app at step 2 if user logged onto the desktop with the user account logged on at step

---

I found this article, but this code will launch the app on current desktop (let's say, currently logged on as userA.  Using username/password of userB, the app is still be launched on userA desktop, but using userB's account).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/165194/createprocessasuser-windowstations-and-desktops

---

Please let me know what's the correct way to achieve my goal.

IDE: Visual Studio 2015 C++ on Windows.

Comment: if you know username/password in what problem ? call `LogonUser` and then `CreateProcessAsUser`

Comment: There is no way to run an application on a desktop that does not yet exist.  Your service must wait for the user to log on, and then launch the application.  Note that there is no need for the service to know the user's password.  Also that in most scenarios a service isn't the best way to do this anyway.

Comment: This assumes (incorrectly) that there is exactly one desktop for a user. The problem is that when the user logs in, a new desktop is created, which will be the second desktop. It won't have the intended window.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for your answer. Does that mean there's no way to create a desktop programatically, which will be used when the user logs in from login screen?  How about remote desktop?  It logs on over network, and create a desktop which will be used later when logs on from login screen.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Thanks for your answer. Does that mean there's no way to login to the machine programatically as same way as user manually logged on from login screen?

Comment: @Aki24x: Don't take my word for it, log in with Remote Desktop, start Notepad, then log in locally and see you get a new desktop without Notepad.  But I suspect this is just another XY problem. You almost certainly shouldn't be doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MSalters, that experiment probably won't work, because by default the user will be attached to the existing session.  (On a Remote Desktop server you can configure whether a user is allowed multiple sessions or not, I'm not sure whether you can reconfigure desktop editions of Windows in the same way.)

Comment: Aki24x, you can [configure automatic logon](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=windows+automatic+logon), but that's usually inappropriate for security reasons.  Theoretically it should be possible to create your own Remote Desktop client (perhaps via the Remote Desktop Protocol Provider API) and log the user into a "remote" session, but it would be very difficult, and I'm not sure how robust it would be.  I strongly recommend that you instead re-architecture your program so that the GUI component doesn't need to be running until the user launches it, or at least until the user logs on.

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes I thought about auto-login, and splitting UI and logic... but neither of them are perfect solution for me right now.  I think the main problem is that as you mentioned in this stackoverflow, on usual Windows, Session cannot be created programatically. 
 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986420/create-a-windows-session-from-a-service-via-the-win32-api)  No session means no WindowStation + Desktop, so no place to launch the app w/UI.  It would be nice if there's a way to switch Desktop after app is launched.  e.g. launched app at Session0, and move it to Session1.

Comment: A process can be moved between desktops, even between window stations, but not between sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer to my question.

**The bottom line is:**

- I cannot launch a process on a desktop of not-logged-on user by programmatically logging in.

**Reason:**

- Calling certain function such as LogOnUser, I can login and access to resources related to user's account.
- However, the logon session is different from a Session which will be created when user logs on from login screen.
- Because of security reason, once a process is launched, we cannot move the process to another Session.  So, UI will never be able to show on the desktop after the user logs on from login screen.

**Alternative solution:**

- Use auto-logon
- Redesign app, and split UI and its data.  So, a process with data can run as service, and UI can launch later on a desktop.

The details explanation of how Windows Session, Window Station, and Desktop works:
https://brianbondy.com/blog/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops

Thank you very much for Harry Johnston for detailed explanation in the comment.